# Am I responsible for cleaning up after a Task created with the TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning flag?

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

When you create a `Task` while specifying `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` a new thread is created specifically for the task.  If you do not specify the `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` then the threadpool is used.

Please correct me if I'm wrong but if the threadpool is used you do not need to `dispose()` the task (as long as you have not used any synchronisation objects inside the task, like `Wait()` on a child task).

If this is the case, am I responsible for cleaning up the extra thread created by using the `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` flag?

If so is the following an acceptable pattern:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {...}, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

task.ContinueWith(x => task.Dispose());
```

Notice how, the `ContinueWith` does not have a `TaskContinuationOptions.LongRunning`, so it *should* use the threadpool.

That being said, however, I have read that the thread that moves the state of the task to `Completed`, `Faulted` or `Cancelled` has a high change of running the continuation.

If someone could shine some light on this I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TaskContinuationOptions.LongRunning` is a *hint* to the Task factory/scheduler, things are not so fixed as you portray it.

I would expect the `ContinueWith` to be executed on the same (longRunning) Thread, that may or may not be running on the ThreadPool.

And as far as I know cleanup of Tasks is automatic, so I wouldn't bother with Dispose() here.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that the flag is a hint rather than a fixed rule.  As for the automatic Task cleanup, I really hope this is the case as it makes working with them much easier. I've +1 for the info but will wait to see if anyone else has extra information to bring to the table. I expect I will be accepting your answer soon!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

Definitely don't call `Dispose()` in a continuation - when are you going to dispose the continuation task?

AFAIK, the only reason `Task` is disposable is to clear up the wait handle created if you wait on the task. If you don't wait on the task, the wait handle will never be created. In any case, the finalizer will clear up eventually.

Also, ***if*** a new thread is created by the Task, it will clean up after itself.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain about the disposal of `Tasks` created with the `LongRunning` option but there are a few things that come to mind about the pattern you've shown.

1. As shown the initial long-running `Task` is not observed which means that if the operation throws an `Exception` for any reason, then it will end up being re-thrown in the Finalizer which would cause the process to crash.
2. The documentation for the `Task` says that you shouldn't call `Dispose` unless the `Task` has actually Completed. So really so you should be checking that `Task` is completed in the continuation if you're going to call dispose.
3. You're actually calling `Dispose` on the `Task` returned by `ContinueWith` not the original, long-running Task.

So you could do something like:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {...}, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)
               .ContinueWith(x => 
   if(x.IsFaulted)
   { 
      x.Exception.Handle(_ => true); //just an example, you'll want to handle properly
   }
   else if(x.IsCompleted)
   {
       //do something with the result, if necessary
       x.Dispose());
   });
```

Ultimately, I think that is more important to observe the `Task` than to `Dispose` it.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  Also, I've updated the code above to reflect your comment about me disposing the wrong task.  

I wrote the code quickly in the question box because I thought it was straight forward enough - haha, go figure I'd make a typo. 

I actually meant to ask about the code the way it is now, where dispose is called on the original task that was created and not the continuation.  So good catch.